# error: package android.test does not exist

Tags: gradle

I can't compile my project!
Please help me.

```
Error:(4, 20) error: package android.test does not exist
Error:(9, 38) error: cannot find symbol class ApplicationTestCase
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

*On Android Stuio 1.4.*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mkurbanov.lebap_kwartira"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'
compile 'com.github.esafirm.android-image-picker:imagepicker:1.13.1'
// for experimental rx picker
compile 'com.github.esafirm.android-image-picker:rximagepicker:1.13.1'
}
```

> //Some Comments Please help me i realy need this! Please help me i
>   realy need this! Please help me i realy need this! Please help me i
>   realy need this! Please help me i realy need this! Please help me i
>   realy need this! Please help me i realy need this! Please help me i
>   realy need this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar Problem with Android Studio 3.3. With "targetSdkVersion 28" I got the Message "error: package android.test does not exist" when I tried to run the application. Compile was possible.
Changing targetSdkVersion to 27 was the workaround